# More complete "MutipartData" POSTs using URLFetch

Tags: web-access, internet

I'm trying to upload a file to a wiki using *Mathematica*'s `URLFetch`. Some preliminary work is required - one needs to log in to the wiki, obtain an edit token, and exchange some cookies with the wiki server. `URLFetch` can handle all of that. But then for the actual file upload, the MediaWiki API (e.g. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Upload) specifies that one has to use the POST method with `Content-Type=multipart/form-data`, but the *Mathematica* implementation of multipart within `URLFetch` seems to be incomplete.

The *Mathematica* documentation of the option `"MultipartData"` of `URLFetch` says only:

> to upload multipart data, each part must be of the form `{name, mimeType, {bytes}}`, where `{bytes}` is a list of bytes

This suggests that in the "Content-Disposition" header of each part of a multipart request, a name can be specified as in:

> ```
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
> ```

but there seems to be no way to also specify a filename, as in

> ```
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Apple.gif"
> ```

Finally, the MediaWiki API requires that a file name be specified; see e.g. the example of a multipart request at the very bottom of http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Upload (and when I try to upload a file without specifying a filename, the wiki server sends back an error message).

So my question: Is there a more complete implementation of the MultiPart protocol with `URLFetch`?

Comment: Try to use `MultiPartData` for the file and then the `Parameters` option (see the section on options) for the file name.

Comment: Tried, failed. At least for MediaWiki, all parameters have to come as parts of of the multipart.

Comment: Dror Bar Natan,
I have the same problem with URLFetch MultipartData / MultipartElements you had almost a year ago. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 13):

This is a hack, but it works.

```
UploadFile[url_, filePath_, urlParams___] := With[
  {
    bytes = Import[filePath, "Byte"],
    filename = StringJoin[FileBaseName[filePath], ".", FileExtension[filePath]]
  },
  URLExecute[
    url,
    urlParams,
    "Method" -> "POST",
    "MultipartElements" -> {
      {"file\"; filename=\"" <> filename, "application/octet-stream", bytes}
    },
    "Headers" -> {
      "Accept" -> "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Content-Type" -> "multipart/form-data",
      "Expect" -> "" (* See edit 2.5 below *)
    }
  ]
]
```

Notice that I'm stuffing the `filename` parameter in the first element of `"MultipartElements"` along with the field name in order to get it in `Content-Disposition` for that element.

```
(* Get a new ephemeral RequestBin from http://requestb.in/, then put URL below: *)
UploadFile["http://requestb.in/1hyjbdl1", "ExampleData/rose.gif"]
```

result:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="rose.gif"
```

Theoretically you could also specify `"Content-Disposition" -> "form-data; filename=\"foo\""` in the request header, but the server would have to be expecting exactly one file in the form-data and parse accordingly, whereas the above approach with filenames in each part I think is more commonly expected.

---

**Edit**

In version 11, there's a no-hack way to do this:

```
image = FindFile["ExampleData/Ocelot.jpg"];
req = HTTPRequest[url, <|
  "Body" -> {"image" -> File[image]},
  "Expect" -> "" (* See edit 2.5 below *)
|>];
URLRead[req, "Body"]
```

[Docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLRead.html) (see Scope > "To send files...")

**Edit 2, 2.5** Mathematica's HTTP client uses `Expect: "100-continue"`, which is not supported by some common load balancers that may be between you and your server. To disable that, add the header `"Expect" -> ""`.

Comment: Thanks for the help answering [another](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97308/how-do-you-submit-an-input-type-of-file-using-urlexecute) question!

Comment: Does the MultipartElements option still accept a third byte list argument?

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock yes, that's the `bytes` symbol in my example, if I understand what you're expecting. Thanks for the reference from the other answer :)

Comment: Oops! I was confused about this point because I ran a "MultipartElements" syntax test that specified elements in mixed format: {"name","mimetype"} -> string and {"name","mimetype",byte-list}. This does not work. The same syntax must be used for all elements.

Comment: Wow,have you notice [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128688/how-to-make-a-python-image-object)?Maybe the `File` can solve?