# URL functions overload

Tags: functions, web-access, guidelines, function-comparison

All these functions seem capable of doing the same things: `Import`, `URLFetch`, `URLSave`, `URLSubmit`, `URLRead`, `URLExecute`. 
I'm confused as to when to use which one.

For web related code, I usually only need to perform POSTs and GETs with header information, authentication and parameters - but I'm overloaded with choices!

So what is the best choice for simple posts and gets? Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: From my experience [this trick](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97777/5478) doesn't work with `URLRead` and I have to work with `URLFetch`.

Comment: [Chat log](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=34678269#34678269) about `URLExecute`.