# Scrape AJAX Website with Webdriver

Tags: import, web-access, webdriver, webunit

I hope the new Webdriver functionality can help as the normal `Import` and `HTTPRequest` don't work.

The sites I have found are a little out there in content (sports betting) but any solution will help on countless other sites.

If you open Chrome, open the Inspector tool and then go to [10bet](https://www.10bet.com/sports/).  You may need to use a VPN depending on where you live.

You will see this call:
[image]

With the response being JSON in the browser.

The same call has these headers:
[image]

The cURL for that call is:

```
curl 'https://www .10bet.com/methods/sportscontent.ashx/GetLeagues?'
-H 'RequestTarget: AJAXService' -H 'Referer: https://www.10bet.com/sports/'
-H 'DNT: 1' -H 'X-JWToken: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJTZXNzaW9uSUQiOiJtdm5zeGd4ZXlicWJ3amZoYXZucHE0ZmEiLCJTaXRlSUQiOiI1NiIsIm5iZiI6MTU1MjQzODUxNCwiZXhwIjoxNTUzMDQzMzE0LCJpYXQiOjE1NTI0Mzg1MTR9.3zQMCUdqkLfMTft-XZXd9GxuFT8NxOaAFTb1iAHtnNI'
-H 'ADRUM: isAjax:true' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_ 14_ 3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --compressed
```

If you transform that cURL into Mathematica it looks like this:

```
request = HTTPRequest["https://www.10bet.com/methods/sportscontent.ashx/GetLeagues?",
        <|Method -> "GET", "ContentType" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "UserAgent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36",
          "Headers" -> <|"X-JWToken" ->"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJTZXNzaW9uSUQiOiJtdm5zeGd4ZXlicWJ3amZoYXZucHE0ZmEiLCJTaXRlSUQiOiI1NiIsIm5iZiI6MTU1MjQzODUxNCwiZXhwIjoxNTUzMDQzMzE0LCJpYXQiOjE1NTI0Mzg1MTR9.3zQMCUdqkLfMTftXZXd9GxuFT8NxOaAFTb1iAHtnNI",
          "RequestTarget" -> "AJAXService", "DNT" -> "1","ADRUM" -> "isAjax:true"|>|>]

URLExecute[request]
```

The request is unsuccessful.

I then use Webdriver to try and navigate to the URL:

```
session = StartExternalSession["WebDriver-Chrome"]
ExternalEvaluate[session, "OpenWebPage" -> "https://www.10bet.com/methods/sportscontent.ashx/GetLeagues?"]
```

The result is not JSON but unevaluated AJAX call.  I am stuck and have no experience with AJAX.  I think one needs to use Webdiver to run a JavaScript script but have no idea how to find the script and therefore use Webdiver to run it.

I would like to interact with the API/JavaScript/AJAX directly and not use Webunit 
to navigate to the page and scrape it that way, if possible.

```
var SportsContentPageMethods={Base:"/methods/sportscontent.ashx/GetLeagues", SBase:"/methods/sportscontent.ashx/GetLeagues", ROBase:"/methods/sportscontent_ros.ashx/GetLeagues", ROSBase:"/methods/sportscontent_ros.ashx/GetLeagues" ,
GetBranchesAndLeagues:function(__shouldGetLeagues,__sc, __ec, __cc) {var p={shouldGetLeagues:__shouldGetLeagues};AJAX.call(false,this.Base,"GetBranchesAndLeagues",p,__sc, __ec, __cc);},
GetLeagues:function(__sc, __ec, __cc) {var p={};AJAX.call(false,this.Base,"GetLeagues",p,__sc, __ec, __cc);},
GetAllLiveContent:function(__sc, __ec, __cc) {var p={};AJAX.call(false,this.Base,"GetAllLiveContent",p,__sc, __ec, __cc);},
GetPartialLiveContent:function(__sc, __ec, __cc) {var p={};AJAX.call(false,this.Base,"GetPartialLiveContent",p,__sc, __ec, __cc);},
GetAllUpcomingContent:function(__nextHoursToLoad,__sc, __ec, __cc) {var p={nextHoursToLoad:__nextHoursToLoad};AJAX.call(false,this.Base,"GetAllUpcomingContent",p,__sc, __ec, __cc);},
GetUpcomingContentPerDay:function(__branchID,__numberOfDaysToAdd,__currentTimeZone,__sc, __ec, __cc) {var p={branchID:__branchID,numberOfDaysToAdd:__numberOfDaysToAdd,currentTimeZone:__currentTimeZone};AJAX.call(false,this.Base,"GetUpcomingContentPerDay",p,__sc, __ec, __cc);},
GetUpcomingDaysWithContent:function(__branchID,__numberOfDaysToAdd,__currentTimeZone,__sc, __ec, __cc) {var p={branchID:__branchID,numberOfDaysToAdd:__numberOfDaysToAdd,currentTimeZone:__currentTimeZone};AJAX.call(false,this.Base,"GetUpcomingDaysWithContent",p,__sc, __ec, __cc);}};
```

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190177/58370) help?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi thank you but that post is about a Mathematica JSON bug (which I have also seen first hand and reported to Wolfram) and they used Python to get around the bug.  That post was making a call and getting a response, my problem is I am not getting a response or don't know how to properly make the call due to the dynamic nature of AJAX.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, my apologies.  You were correct that the problem was importing.  I never checked the status code to see if the request was successful or not so I assumed the call was failing.

Comment: No worries. Looks like @CarlLange (yet again) came up with a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, the request is not unsuccessful (it gives a 200 status code). However, the JSON it returns throws an error when you attempt to import it: `"An error occurred near character ',', at line 1:97"`, and thus `URLExecute` fails, because it tries to automatically import the result correctly.

However, the response is essentially just a big list of rows for a table, so we can get around this limitation by importing it as a CSV format instead.

The following code prints out the same structure as the browser:

```
request = 
 HTTPRequest[
  "https://www.10bet.com/methods/sportscontent.ashx/GetLeagues?", <|
   Method -> "GET", 
   "ContentType" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
   "UserAgent" -> 
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) \
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 \
Safari/537.36", 
   "Headers" -> <|
     "X-JWToken" -> 
      "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJTZXNzaW9uSUQiOiJtdm5zeGd\
4ZXlicWJ3amZoYXZucHE0ZmEiLCJTaXRlSUQiOiI1NiIsIm5iZiI6MTU1MjQzODUxNCwiZ\
XhwIjoxNTUzMDQzMzE0LCJpYXQiOjE1NTI0Mzg1MTR9.\
3zQMCUdqkLfMTftXZXd9GxuFT8NxOaAFTb1iAHtnNI", 
     "RequestTarget" -> "AJAXService", "DNT" -> "1", 
     "ADRUM" -> "isAjax:true"|>|>]

body = URLRead[request]["Body"]
```

Now we can import the result as CSV, if we replace "[" with the empty string and "]" with a new line. (We use `Most` to avoid a final empty row).

```
data = Most@ImportString[StringReplace[body, {"[" -> "", "]" -> "\n"}], 
  "CSV"]
```

will import the data as a big list of rows.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help.  I never thought to check the status code of the call.  I hope Mathematica fixes that JSON bug!  There are a lot more calls (to different routes) to the site I would like to make and if they fail, will report back.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me that the JSON issue is actually a bug, but if I'm honest I spent no time whatsoever debugging it :) `JavaScriptExpression` is also an option as an `Import` format that might be worth checking out (though it has the same issue in this case).

Comment: @RayTroy The JSON is invalid because it has consecutive commas in it, which isn't allowed.

Comment: @CarlLange do you think there is a way to preserve the structure and not have it be a flat lists of lists?  I would like to keep the nesting of the lists.

Comment: @RayTroy Ah, I honestly didn't notice that the data wasn't just a flat structure. I'm afraid I don't have time to spend on it now - I would probably end up just playing around with mapping `Partition` over the data to add the structure back in.