# Import data from a webpage with dynamically generated content

Tags: import, json-format

Following the example of this very detailed thread [190177](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190177/import-data-from-dynamically-generated-webpage) and others related to the subject, that introduced me to snooping around in the developer's tools, I tried to apply to my case, which is retrieving name information from a phonebook lookup service in Greek, e.g https://www.11888.gr/phone_catalog/?phone=2103232913. I can see that the page is dynamically generated via a script. I can even parse the url snatched from the developer's tools, [this one](https://avalanche.11888.gr/i?category=Anypage&action=Page.Loaded&eventType=page_view&userId=&pageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.11888.gr%2Fphone_catalog%2F%3Fphone%3D2103232913&jsPageReferrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.11888.gr%2F&appId=11888&platform=web&test=false&eventCreatedAt=1562922283426&AVALANCHE_UID=6935370e08cffda11e438e88d53e0180fdadbc82d9410ad3e8329a065c31460a%3AEhfPRh7hYzmhK4wqUyVehWYs_tA&_=1562922281049) and Mathematica recognises that there's a request and outputs

```
<|"Scheme" -> "https", "User" -> None, 
 "Domain" -> "avalanche.11888.gr", "Port" -> None, 
 "Path" -> {"", "i"}, 
 "Query" -> {"category" -> "Anypage", "action" -> "Page.Loaded", 
   "eventType" -> "page_view", "userId" -> "", 
   "pageUrl" -> 
    "https://www.11888.gr/phone_catalog/?phone=2103232913", 
   "jsPageReferrer" -> "https://www.11888.gr/", "appId" -> "11888", 
   "platform" -> "web", "test" -> "false", 
   "eventCreatedAt" -> "1562922283426", 
   "AVALANCHE_UID" -> "6935370e08cffda11e438e88d53e0180fdadbc82d9410ad3e8329a065c31460a:\
EhfPRh7hYzmhK4wqUyVehWYs_tA", "_" -> "1562922281049"}, 
 "Fragment" -> None|>
```

However the rest of the code from the above related page doesn't work. I can't import JSON data either via Python or via Mathematica and I get a 500: Internal Server Error.

```
FetchURL::httperr: The request to URL https://avalanche.11888.gr/i?category=Anypage&action=\[Ellipsis] 5c31460a%3AEhfPRh7hYzmhK4wqUyVehWYs_tA&_=1562922281049 was not successful. The server returned the HTTP status code 500 ("Internal Server Error").
```

So, what is different about this page than the NBA one in the aforementioned post? How can I get the data from it? Is it not a JSON case at all?

I should mention I'm using v11.3 on a Raspberry Pi 3.