# Importing from an API that has non UTF-8 strings

Tags: import, web-access, json-format, unicode

I am new to both Mathematica and API's. I am trying to access a dictionary of player-ids to names from the website datdota.com, but some of them have chinese characters.

relevant code:
    `URLExecute["http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543"]`

When I run this I get the error "cannot import data as JSON format".

I tried to get around it with
    `URLExecute["http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543", 
 CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]`

but i got the same error.

Is there a different function I need to use? How can I access this data?

Here's a link to what I'm trying to access: http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543

Comment: This works fine for me.  What version are you using?

Comment: `Import["http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543", "JSON"]` evaluates fine on my end (11.2 on Linux).

Comment: @ItaiSeggev pre 11.3 I guess.

Comment: `ImportString[FromCharacterCode[URLRead["http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543", "BodyBytes"]], "JSON"]` worked on v11.2 Windows. Stems from [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154245/who-is-to-blame-parsing-utf8-encoded-json-httpresponse-fails] also `URLExecute["http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543",  "Text", 
 CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]` return an encoded result but difficult to return to JSON that can be parsed.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev I'm using 11.1. on a Mac

Comment: @J.M. Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh what a mess:

```
    ImportString[
 FromCharacterCode[
  ToCharacterCode[
   URLExecute["http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543",  "Text"], 
   "UTF8"]], "JSON"]
(*{"data" -> {"nickname" -> "跳刀跳刀丶", "steam_id" -> "101586543"}}*)
```

V11.2 Windows

In order to answer poster's questions: "Is there a different function I need to use? How can I access this data?" As @J. M. commented

```
Import["http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543", "JSON"]
```

should work. Nevertheless, this particular hic-cup you ran into seems to be a known issue in WL when using `URLExcecute`. The above workaround solution is there just in case you also need to work with API with more parameter passing.

Comment: The problem with `"Text"` may be that it is supposed to infer encoding etc and it is not defined well. `"String"` should be more stable as kind of raw bytes string but `"String"` changed in 11.3 while `"Text"` didn't XD. Daily fun.

Comment: @Kuba `"String"` works. Also using the encoding `"Custom"` in the From and To ..Encode seems to work. I tried many other available  encodings  such as `"ShiftJIS"`, `"UTF-8"` over `"UTF8"`some worked, some did not.

Answer (score 3):

It could be related to all this 'content-type' mess: [Who is to blame: parsing UTF8 encoded JSON HTTPResponse fails](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154245/5478), but there are no messages issued before failure so I'm not so sure.

I think the issue was known because:

- V10.4 returns `$Failed` and `Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as JSON format. >>`
- V11.2 returns `Failure` with `ImportFailure tag. No messages.
- V11.3 returns correct association

For pre 11.3 use either `Import` or linked route through `"BodyBytes"`:

```
ImportString[ FromCharacterCode @ URLRead[ 
  "http://datdota.com/api/players/101586543", "BodyBytes"]
, "RawJSON"
]
```

> ```
> <|"data" -> <|"nickname" -> "跳刀跳刀丶", "steam_id" -> "101586543"|>|>
> ```