# How to ImportString "JSON" with Unicode characters?

Tags: import, character-encoding, json-format

### Update

The short answer is that when getting results back from an API into an `HTTPResponse` object the `"Body"` property is a *post-decoded* form of the result.  `ImportString` with `"JSON"` expects the *encoded* form of the result.  Therefore you should use the `"BodyBytes"` property with `FromCharacterCode`.

With `res` a `HTTPResponse` object with the result, then

```
ImportString[FromCharacterCode@res["BodyBytes"], "JSON"]
```

brings in the result without issue.

`URLExecute` can also be used to directly return the imported JSON but you don't get a nice `HTTPResponse` object to check the status of your result.

With `req` a `HTTPRequest` object, then

```
URLExecute[req, {}, "JSON"]
```

brings in the result without issue.

---

### OP

I have many large JSON results from a web API that contain Unicode characters.  `ImportString` with `"JSON"` seems unable to import these.  As a minimal example try,

```
ImportString["{\"id\":1,\"text\":\"ñía\"}", "JSON"]
```

> Import::utf8expcontinuation: Input is not a valid UTF8 byte sequence. 237 is expected to be a continuation byte.
>
> Import::jsonhintposition: An error occurred at line 1:19

I have tried adding option `CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"` and get the same result.

Finally I tried

```
# -> ImportString["{\"id\":1,\"text\":\"ñía\"}", "JSON", 
    CharacterEncoding -> #] & /@ $CharacterEncodings
```

Every encoding failed.

How do I import Unicode JSON? I have many such results to import.

I am using Win10 Mma 11.3

Comment: Round tripping to and from `ByteArray` works on your small example for some encodings: `Cases[Quiet[# -> ImportString[ByteArrayToString[StringToByteArray["{\"id\":1,\"text\":\"ñía\"}"], #], "JSON"]] & /@ $CharacterEncodings, _[_, _List]]`

Comment: @ChipHurst A few of them do work with the round trip. Any ideas why hoops must be jumped through to get what should be a basic import.  Bug, perhaps?

Comment: It feels like a bug, but I don’t have enough background to know for sure.

Comment: Where does this string come from? If from URLRead Body then it is not the way to go and you have to import bytes > FromCharacterCode > ImportString. For explanation see the first section in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154245/5478

Comment: @Kuba `ImportString[FromCharacterCode@res["BodyBytes"], "JSON"]` for `res` a `HTTPResponse` object does the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: @Edmund maybe we should put that line somewhere on top of the linked question as TL;DR for future visitors. It became quite long and may not be clear anymore, otoh everything is relevant

Comment: @Kuba `URLExecute[req, {}, "JSON"]` with `req` a `HTTPRequest` object is even better and it comes in already parsed as a list of rules. However, it is not as easy to check for success since you don't get a `HTTPResponse` object.

Comment: @Edmund yes if URLExecute can be used then go with it. Sometimes one needs to use `URLRead` when a more fine grained control is needed.

Comment: Another option here is to use ```Developer`ReadRawJSONString``` since it has no problem with your string.