# Bug in WebExecute TypeElement with diacritics characters [Solved]

Tags: bugs, web-access, character-encoding

[Solved in 12.1.1]

When using `WebExecute` `TypeElement`, I get `$Failed` if I have a diacritics character in the submitted string. Here is a minimal example:

```
session = StartWebSession["Chrome"];
WebExecute["OpenPage"->"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126293/how-to-set-text-into-textarea-with-selenium-webdriver"];
textArea = First@WebExecute["LocateElements"->"XPath"->"//*[@id=\"wmd-input\"]"];
WebExecute["TypeElement"->{textArea, "à"}]
```

If I change `"à"` to `"a"`, it works so far so good.

Any clue?

[crosspost in Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1897363)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kuba is right with his solution and we need to patch this in the `WebUnit` code.

Everything in the `WebUnit` code eventually runs through a single `fetch` function
which makes the browser command request to the web-driver executable (a small binary which controls the browser).

In my personal experience these requests work most reliable by switching to byte arrays, so this is an initial draft of a solution I am going to propose to fix the issue.

```
ClearAll[WebUnit`Private`fetch];

WebUnit`Private`fetch[
 WebUnit`Private`sessioninfo_,
 WebUnit`Private`type_, 
 WebUnit`Private`path_, 
 WebUnit`Private`data_,
 WebUnit`Private`key_
] := Module[{
 WebUnit`Private`res, 
 WebUnit`Private`fetchResult
},
 WebUnit`Private`fetchResult = URLRead[
  HTTPRequest[
   WebUnit`Private`sessioninfo[[3]] <> WebUnit`Private`path, <|
    "Method" -> WebUnit`Private`type,
    "Body" -> WebUnit`Private`json[WebUnit`Private`data]
   |>
  ], "BodyByteArray"
 ]; 
 If[
  !ByteArrayQ[WebUnit`Private`fetchResult], 
  Return[$Failed]
 ]; 
 If[
  ImportByteArray[WebUnit`Private`fetchResult, "Text"] === "missing command parameters",
  Return[$Failed]
 ];
 WebUnit`Private`res = ImportByteArray[WebUnit`Private`fetchResult, "JSON"]; 
 WebUnit`Private`DebugPrint[ WebUnit`Private`format[WebUnit`Private`res] ]; 
 WebUnit`Private`key /. WebUnit`Private`res
]
```

As far as I can tell this also fixes your problem and I also tested it with this example:

```
b = StartWebSession[]
WebExecute[b, "OpenWebPage" -> "https://www.google.com"]
WebExecute[b, "JavascriptExecute" -> "document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value='bábáç'"]
```

Comment: Tks Arnoud! It would be nice to have it in version 12.1

Comment: I tested in my code. It's worked nice to `TypeElement ` too. Tks again.

Answer (score 3):

Full answer and explanation probably involves a lot of fun time tracking encoding performed internally. And I won't [spend it that way again](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154245/5478).

You can use `PrintDeifinitions` or

```
Trace[ WebExecute["TypeElement" -> {textArea, text_}], _URLFetch]
```

To see that the call is:

```
URLFetch["http://localhost:{port}/session/{sessionId}/element/{elementId}/value",
  "Method" -> "Post", "BodyData" -> "{
    \"value\":[
        characters...
    ]
  }"]
```

Something goes wrong and characters are not encoded correctly nor the response is parsed correctly.

Here is a quick workaround:

```
typeElementPath // ClearAll

typeElementPath[elem : _WebElementObject, text_] := Module[{url},

  url = URLBuild[
    <| URLParse @ elem["URL"], 
     "Path" -> {"session", elem["SessionID"], "element", elem["ElementId"]}|>
  ];

  URLExecute[
   HTTPRequest[
    url <> "/clear",
    <| "Method" -> "Post"|> 
   ]   
  ];

  URLExecute[
   HTTPRequest[
    url <> "/value",
    <|
     "Method" -> "Post",
     "Body" -> ExportString[<|"value" -> Characters@text|>, "RawJSON", "Compact" -> True]
     |>,
    CharacterEncoding -> None
    ],
   "RawJSON"
   ]
  ]
```

```
typeElementPath[textArea, "αó"]
```

> ```
> <|"sessionId" -> "a0c4c6e971d1506dd115351a76278480", "status" -> 0,  "value" -> Null|>
> ```

[image]

You can skip the first `URLExecute` to append instead of overwrite the element.

This should work for IE/Chrome/Edge. For Firefox you probably just need to use:

```
 ExportString[<|"text" -> text|>, "RawJSON", "Compact" -> True]
```

But I have not tested it.

Comment: Really annoying this encoding bug. Thanks for your answer @Kuba. I'll wait 2 day before accept.