# How to call Picture Bed API

Tags: web-access, python, object-oriented, api

I want to call this [Picture bed API](https://sm.ms/doc/) to upload my picture and return its link.I have translated [the official instructional the page](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-10-14-17-42-03.png) into English.And there is [a example](https://link.zhihu.com/?target=https%3A//github.com/kingname/MarkdownPicPicker/blob/master/uploader/SmUploader.py) succeed to use it with **Python**. I want to use it in **Mathematica** also, but the parameter (`smfile`) seem is *Python image object*.Such as following try.So how to make it?The `img` in code is

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-10-14-17-53-00.png

**Try one:**

```
URLExecute["https://sm.ms/api/upload", <|"Method" -> "POST", 
  "smfile" -> img|>]
```

**Try two:**

```
URLExecute["https://sm.ms/api/upload", <|"Method" -> "POST", 
  "smfile" -> 
   FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode[ImageData[img], "UTF-8"], 
    "Unicode"]|>]
```

I think the key of failure is that `"smfile"` should be a *Python object* but not a common Mathematica expression or maybe there are other workaround can do this.

Comment: Please make this question self contained. Include your mma code and explanation what is going wrong.

Comment: "smfile is a Python image object" -- the docs suggest it a normal PNG file. Have you tried the method in the post that you commented on (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97658/1043)?

Comment: @ZachB Yes,I have noted that post and give some try,but I am lack of this area knowledge.I don't know how to do it still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `URLFetch[]`:

```
smmsUpload[img_, detailed : (True | False) : False] := Module[{raw}, 
    raw = ImportString[URLFetch["https://sm.ms/api/upload", Method -> "POST", 
                                "MultipartElements" -> {{"smfile\"; filename=\"tmp.png", 
                                "image/png"} -> ExportString[img, "PNG"]}], "RawJSON"];
    If[raw === $Failed || Lookup[raw, "code", "error"] =!= "success",
       Echo[raw["msg"]]; Return[$Failed]];
    If[! detailed, raw["data", "url"],
       Grid[Transpose[{{"Dimensions:", "Hash:", "Image Link:", "Delete Link:"}, 
                       MapAt[Hyperlink, FlattenAt[TakeDrop[
                       Lookup[raw["data"], {"width", "height", "hash", "url", "delete"}],
                              2], 2], {{3}, {4}}]}], Alignment -> Left]]]

smmsUpload[ExampleData[{"AerialImage", "Pentagon"}], True]
```

[image: result]

I couldn't get `URLRead[]`/`URLExecute[]` to work, so I'll leave that for somebody else to do.

Comment: That `If` scare me, actually this answer is what I want exactly which can upload a image produced compute.Thanks very much,maybe you can change the `URLFetch` to `URLRead` enlightened by [SqRoots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21504/sqroots)'s answer.

Comment: As your answer,I think `HTTPRequest["https://sm.ms/api/upload",<|Method -> "POST","Body"->{"smfile"-><|"Content" -> ExportString[img,"PNG"],"MIMEType" -> "image/png","filename" -> "tmp.png"|>}|>]` should work,but I don't know what happen.

Comment: Did you try your proposal already if it works?

Comment: [That](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128688/how-to-call-picture-bed-api#comment348290_128730) work,Would you mind update your answer?

Answer (score 3):

In Mma 11, you can use this function `URLRead[]`.

e.g.

```
image = "E:/yourPic.jpg";(*Your Picture*)
url = "https://sm.ms/api/upload";(*Picture Bed URL*)
req = HTTPRequest[url, <|"Body" -> {"smfile" -> <|"Content" -> File[image], 
    "Name" -> FileNameTake[image]|>}|>];(*Upload Request, the "Name" is unnecessary*)
res = URLRead[req, "Body"];(*Upload, return JSON String*)
assoc = ImportString[res, "RawJSON"](*convert to Association*)
```

Then, `assoc` is what you want.

- URL: `assoc["data"]["url"]`
- delete: `ImportString[URLRead[assoc["data"]["delete"], "Body"]]`
- size: `assoc["data"]["size"]`
- width: `assoc["data"]["width"]`
- height: `assoc["data"]["height"]`

Comment: `"Name"` is certainly unnecessary if the image is coming from a file, but what would you propose if the image is already in *Mathematica*? Exporting it as a file just to upload it seems wasteful...

Comment: I think it is wasteful for I/O, but not to much for CPU. *yode*'s way works, and not need export.