# How to call Imgur API

Tags: web-access, api

My image host returns a link starting with `http://`. It seems this format is not supported in SE anymore. To avoid this, I want to change the image host to **Imgur**. But I have failed to call it right.

There is a code write by [Arnoud Buzing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028599/arnoud-buzing) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345690/7033055):

```
Import["http://api.imgur.com/2/upload", "XML", 
       "RequestMethod" -> "POST", 
       "RequestParameters" -> {"key" -> apikey, "image" -> image}]
```

But it does not seem to work anymore.

And this code derived from [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan)

```
$file = Export["tmp/img.png", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], "PNG"];
$req = HTTPRequest[
   "https://api.imgur.com/3/image", <|Method -> "Post", 
    "Headers" -> {"Authorization" -> "Client-ID 93d5e807261cc90", 
      "Accept" -> "application/json"}, 
    "Body" -> {"image" -> File[$file], "type" -> "file"}|>];
URLRead[$req];
Import[%]
```

Actually I'm out of the firewall now and I can upload images using [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBsGs.jpg), but I get the following error information from [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan)'s code:

> {status->500,success->False,data->{error->Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later.}}

---

This is my Imgur API information for *testing*. If this question is solved, I will change it maybe.

```
Client_Name:mmascript
Client_ID:93d5e807261cc90
Client_Secret:04eacd2b7aeb76b551d9c33a02ddbac4a27f8aa4
```

Comment: Can confirm halirutan's code works, which it should, as it's exactly what's in the [API docs](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload).

Comment: @MB1965 I just suspect that format of [*Key*](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-03-15-07-38-38.png)

Comment: what exactly do you mean? That's just saying that we have to specify "image" in the body, but the others are optional. Furthermore copying and evaluating halirutan's code returns a 200 for me, plus `success->True` in the json output.

Comment: try it with the exact input structure halirutan sent. That is, use a `File` object and leave `"type"->"file"`. Or you could try encoding your data as `base64` which seems to be another acceptable form.

Comment: @MB1965 Oh,sorry,I give a wrong image,it should be [this](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-03-15-07-53-24.png).And I don't know the disable related [this statement](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/207868493-Blocked-from-Uploading).

Comment: ahhh, I think I know what's up. Read [this](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2#registration). If you're blocked from using the service without logging in you may need to get an auth token first.

Comment: @MB1965 Are you availabe now [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36044949#36044949)?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a starting point: after getting your own client ID from [here](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient), use the following code, which uses `URLFetch[]` like in [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128730):

```
imgurUpload[img_] := Module[{clientID = "93d5e807261cc90", raw},
  raw = ImportString[URLFetch["https://api.imgur.com/3/image", Method -> "POST", 
                              "Headers" -> {"Authorization" -> "Client-ID " <> clientID}, 
                              "MultipartElements" -> {{"image\"; filename=\"test.png", 
                                                       "image/png"} ->
                              ExportString[img, "PNG"]}], "RawJSON"];
  If[raw === $Failed || ! Lookup[raw, "success"], 
     Echo[raw["data", "error"]]; Return[$Failed]];
  raw["data", "link"]]
```

I'll leave the writing of a version that uses `URLRead[]`/`URLExecute[]` to somebody else.

Comment: I provided an `HTTPRequest` version of that [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/55390?m=36045553#36045553). I think the issue ended up not being Mathematica. Things were failing for him that weren't for me, which could have been related to a message imgur put out about service disruptions around various parts of the globe.

Comment: The code writed by halirutan actully work,but I find the [API](http://api.imgur.com/) is blocked in my area after I invite some friends from different city and country to test.