# How to upload an image to the Stack Exchange Imgur account?

Tags: web-access, api

This is ***not*** a duplicate of [How to call Imgur API](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139913/how-to-call-imgur-api).

I tried to upload to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) using its [API](http://api.imgur.com/), but (as my friends test) the [API of imgur](http://api.imgur.com/) cannot be called in Chinese mainland. Then I found that  [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) has a technology to upload an image to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) even without any account information via `http://stackoverflow.com/upload/image`. Now I can upload image to imgur by his function `` SEUploader`sendImage ``. Little pity is that he implemented it with Java code.

We can find his code [here](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools/blob/master/src/de/halirutan/se/tools/SEUploader.java). I get nothing after researching his Java code. Can we do the same thing  in pure *Mathematica* using new functions introduced in version 11.0 such as `HTTPRequest`, `URLRead` and so on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update on June 29th, 2020

Since API has changed, the new code is here:

```
getFKey[] := 
 First@StringCases[
   URLRead[HTTPRequest["https://stackexchange.com"]]["Body"], 
   "fkey: '" ~~ Shortest[fkey___] ~~ "'" :> fkey]
uploadImageSE[imagePath_] := 
 Module[{req}, 
  req = HTTPRequest[
    "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/upload/image?method=json&\
https=true", <|Method -> "POST", 
     "Body" -> {"file" -> File[imagePath], "fkey" -> getFKey[]}|>];
  ImportString[URLRead[req]["Body"], "RawJSON"]["UploadedImage"]]
```

---

This is expected to work with `jpg` and `png` files. You need to input the path to image, just like an upload.

```
uploadImageSE[imagePath_] := 
 Module[{req}, 
  req = HTTPRequest[
    "http://stackoverflow.com/upload/image", <|
     
     "Body" -> {"image" -> <|"Content" -> File[imagePath], 
         "MIMEType" -> "image/png"|>}
     |>];
  StringCases[URLRead[req, "Body"], "http" ~~ __ ~~ ".jpg" | ".png"] //
    First]


uploadImageSE["/Users/xxx/Downloads/test.png"]
(*"https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD80b.png"*)
```

Remember to remove the double quotes before accessing.

Comment: That *java* code mislead me.Orz...

Comment: If you've already set `"MIMEType" -> "image/png"`, then you don't need to search for `".jpg"`. You can do something like `First[StringCases[URLRead[req, "Body"], RegularExpression["closeDialog\\(\"(.+)\"\\)"] -> "$1"]]`.

Comment: @J.M. even if I set it to be png, I found the uploaded file to be `.jpg` sometimes when the original file is `.jpg`

Comment: Ah. In that case, the `StringCases[]` code I gave should work no matter what the file extension is.